# Convert x ticks sampling points to time series on x axis (knowing sampling rate)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a numpy array `data` of light intensity values sampled along a line (length = **12500**) for **50** times (cycles).

```
data.shape
>>> (50, 12500)
```

I correctly generated the following heatmap:

```
sns.heatmap(data.T, cmap='binary_r') # T because I want it to be shown transposed
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKDsH.png)

So that I have the 12500 sampling points along the line on the y axis and the cycle number on the x axis (50 cycles).

**I would like to convert the x axis ticks to a time series knowing that completing all the 50 cycles takes 500 ms.**

I have tried the following to get 10 ticks every 50 ms:

```
timestamps = np.linspace(0, 500, 11, dtype=float)
sns.heatmap(data.T, cmap='binary_r')
plt.xticks(timestamps)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ODOB.png)

But it seems to keep the original x ticks and simply shrink down the heatmap to fit within the new x axis range.

I tried as well to workaround it by simply changing the x labels:

```
timestamps = np.linspace(0, 500, 11, dtype=float)
sns.heatmap(data.T, cmap='binary_r')
plt.xlabel(timestamps)
```

But what I obtained:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lT7l.png)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I post a solution that worked in case someone might need it:

```
timestamps = np.linspace(0, 500, 11, dtype=float)
sns.heatmap(data.T, cmap='binary_r')
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, 50, 11, dtype=int), timestamps)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvI51.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).